# How to add a loop to make multiple "two-group" scatter plots, and then automatically give same y-axis limits to both groups in each plot?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, yaxis

I have 2 questions here that are connected:

(1) I am interested in making 2 scatter plots (Group1 on left and Group2 on right), both for hundreds of Genes. Each gene with these 2 plots are to be printed in separate png files. I am already able to do so 'per' gene. However, I have hundreds of genes, and would therefore like to add a loop for each gene. I have given an example dataset below for 2 genes: Gene1 and Gene2.

(2) Things get a bit more complicated for me because y-axis scales are different for every gene. I am aware of adding "scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.07))" to both Group1 and Group2 to make the scales comparable in a single png file. However, when running a loop for hundreds of genes, how can I let the y-axis be the same when dealing with different scales for every gene?

Here is my example data frame called 'data'.

```
Biomarkers  TimePoint   Groups  Scale   Readings
Gene1   52.5    Group1  10  0.021066
Gene1   52.5    Group2  10  0.019844
Gene1   57.5    Group1  10  0.024328
Gene1   57.5    Group2  10  0.016862
Gene1   62.5    Group1  10  0.023408
Gene1   62.5    Group2  10  0.018715
Gene1   52.5    Group1  25  0.0271
Gene1   52.5    Group2  25  0.0240525
Gene1   57.5    Group1  25  0.0289975
Gene1   57.5    Group2  25  0.023015
Gene1   62.5    Group1  25  0.029795
Gene1   62.5    Group2  25  0.0235975
Gene1   52.5    Group1  50  0.03457
Gene1   52.5    Group2  50  0.02917
Gene1   57.5    Group1  50  0.039255
Gene1   57.5    Group2  50  0.03051
Gene1   62.5    Group1  50  0.037835
Gene1   62.5    Group2  50  0.029515
Gene1   52.5    Group1  75  0.0446
Gene1   52.5    Group2  75  0.0382675
Gene1   57.5    Group1  75  0.047695
Gene1   57.5    Group2  75  0.0411
Gene1   62.5    Group1  75  0.04727
Gene1   62.5    Group2  75  0.04001
Gene1   52.5    Group1  90  0.056192
Gene1   52.5    Group2  90  0.046091
Gene1   57.5    Group1  90  0.062609
Gene1   57.5    Group2  90  0.04831
Gene1   62.5    Group1  90  0.059525
Gene1   62.5    Group2  90  0.051676
Gene2   52.5    Group1  10  0.019224
Gene2   52.5    Group2  10  0.012512
Gene2   57.5    Group1  10  0.019476
Gene2   57.5    Group2  10  0.017973
Gene2   62.5    Group1  10  0.022266
Gene2   62.5    Group2  10  0.018438
Gene2   52.5    Group1  25  0.02633
Gene2   52.5    Group2  25  0.02284
Gene2   57.5    Group1  25  0.02686
Gene2   57.5    Group2  25  0.023725
Gene2   62.5    Group1  25  0.030415
Gene2   62.5    Group2  25  0.0247175
Gene2   52.5    Group1  50  0.03813
Gene2   52.5    Group2  50  0.03047
Gene2   57.5    Group1  50  0.0384
Gene2   57.5    Group2  50  0.031035
Gene2   62.5    Group1  50  0.04037
Gene2   62.5    Group2  50  0.03219
Gene2   52.5    Group1  75  0.05681
Gene2   52.5    Group2  75  0.04059
Gene2   57.5    Group1  75  0.05618
Gene2   57.5    Group2  75  0.039695
Gene2   62.5    Group1  75  0.05748
Gene2   62.5    Group2  75  0.0429125
Gene2   52.5    Group1  90  0.090266
Gene2   52.5    Group2  90  0.059884
Gene2   57.5    Group1  90  0.092606
Gene2   57.5    Group2  90  0.053052
Gene2   62.5    Group1  90  0.088748
Gene2   62.5    Group2  90  0.0571
```

The dput for my data is:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Biomarkers = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Gene1", "Gene2"), class = "factor"), 
    TimePoint = c(52.5, 52.5, 57.5, 57.5, 62.5, 62.5, 52.5, 52.5, 
    57.5, 57.5, 62.5, 62.5, 52.5, 52.5, 57.5, 57.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
    52.5, 52.5, 57.5, 57.5, 62.5, 62.5, 52.5, 52.5, 57.5, 57.5, 
    62.5, 62.5, 52.5, 52.5, 57.5, 57.5, 62.5, 62.5, 52.5, 52.5, 
    57.5, 57.5, 62.5, 62.5, 52.5, 52.5, 57.5, 57.5, 62.5, 62.5, 
    52.5, 52.5, 57.5, 57.5, 62.5, 62.5, 52.5, 52.5, 57.5, 57.5, 
    62.5, 62.5), Groups = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Group1", 
    "Group2"), class = "factor"), Scale = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
    50L, 50L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
    90L, 90L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
    25L, 25L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
    75L, 75L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L), Readings = c(0.021066, 
    0.019844, 0.024328, 0.016862, 0.023408, 0.018715, 0.0271, 
    0.0240525, 0.0289975, 0.023015, 0.029795, 0.0235975, 0.03457, 
    0.02917, 0.039255, 0.03051, 0.037835, 0.029515, 0.0446, 0.0382675, 
    0.047695, 0.0411, 0.04727, 0.04001, 0.056192, 0.046091, 0.062609, 
    0.04831, 0.059525, 0.051676, 0.019224, 0.012512, 0.019476, 
    0.017973, 0.022266, 0.018438, 0.02633, 0.02284, 0.02686, 
    0.023725, 0.030415, 0.0247175, 0.03813, 0.03047, 0.0384, 
    0.031035, 0.04037, 0.03219, 0.05681, 0.04059, 0.05618, 0.039695, 
    0.05748, 0.0429125, 0.090266, 0.059884, 0.092606, 0.053052, 
    0.088748, 0.0571)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

And here is my code that I am able to make per gene (Group1 and Group2) for one png file.

```
# Load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

# Data select
data_select <- data[ data$Biomarkers %in% "Gene1", ]
data_Group1 <- data_select[ data_select$Groups %in% "Group1", ]
data_Group2 <- data_select[ data_select$Groups %in% "Group2", ]

png ("ScatterPlot_Gene1.png", height=600, width=1111)

# Group1
graph_Group1 <- data_Group1 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = data_Group1$TimePoint,
        y = data_Group1$Readings,
        group = data_Group1$Scale)) +
    labs(title="Group1", x="Time point", y="Readings") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5),
        labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) +
    geom_line(aes(color = data_Group1$Scale), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_point(aes(color = data_Group1$Scale),
                size = 1.5,
                na.rm = TRUE) +
    scale_color_continuous(name = "Scale",
        breaks = c(5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90)) +
    theme(legend.key.height = unit(3.5, "cm"))
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.07))

# Group2
graph_Group2 <- data_Group2 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = data_Group2$TimePoint,
        y = data_Group2$Readings,
        group = data_Group2$Scale)) +
    labs(title="Group2", x="Time point", y="Readings") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5),
        labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) +
    geom_line(aes(color = data_Group2$Scale), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_point(aes(color = data_Group2$Scale),
                size = 1.5,
                na.rm = TRUE) +
    scale_color_continuous(name = "Scale",
        breaks = c(5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90)) +
    theme(legend.key.height = unit(3.5, "cm"))
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.07))

grid.arrange(graph_Group1, graph_Group2, nrow = 1, top=textGrob("Gene1",gp=gpar(fontsize=20)))
dev.off()
```

And here is my current figure.
[image]

Any help appreciated. Thanking you.

Comment: Are the scales in your #2 not desired in current figure? By the way never use `$` inside `aes`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have now added dput for my data. The scales for Group2 is desired as I have set it that way through "scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.07))" but I need it to be automatic since it would be different for every gene.

Comment: How did you determine those limits? Are they min/max of both groups?

Comment: Yes exactly. They are min/max of both groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider generalizing your plotting process in a method and call `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) to iteratively run operation on each unique gene. For scales, calculate the min and max *Reading* between both groups beforehand:

**User-Defined Function**

```
proc_plot <- function(sub) {

  data_Group1 <- sub[sub$Groups == "Group1", ]
  data_Group2 <- sub[sub$Groups == "Group2", ]

  min_rdg <- min(data_Group1$Readings, data_Group2$Readings)
  max_rdg <- max(data_Group1$Readings, data_Group2$Readings)

  # Group1
  graph_Group1 <- ggplot(data_Group1, aes(x = TimePoint, y = Readings, group = Scale)) +
    labs(title="Group1", x="Time point", y="Readings") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5),
                       labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Scale), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Scale),size = 1.5, na.rm = TRUE) +
    scale_color_continuous(name = "Scale", breaks = c(5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min_rdg, max_rdg)) +
    theme(legend.key.height = unit(3.5, "cm"))

  # Group2
  graph_Group2 <- ggplot(data_Group2, aes(x = TimePoint, y = Readings, group = Scale)) +
    labs(title="Group2", x="Time point", y="Readings") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5),
                       labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Scale), na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_point(aes(color = Scale), size = 1.5, na.rm = TRUE) +
    scale_color_continuous(name = "Scale", breaks = c(5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min_rdg, max_rdg)) +
    theme(legend.key.height = unit(3.5, "cm"))

  png (paste0("ScatterPlot_", sub$Biomarkers[[1]], ".png"), height=600, width=1111)
    output <- grid.arrange(graph_Group1, graph_Group2, nrow = 1, 
                           top=textGrob(sub$Biomarkers[[1]], gp=gpar(fontsize=20)))
  dev.off()

  return(output)
}
```

**Plot Call**

```
# BUILD PLOT LIST AND PNG FILES
plot_list <- by(data, data$Biomarkers, proc_plot)
```

**Display Saved Plots**

```
dev.off()
grid.draw(plot_list$Gene1)

dev.off()
grid.draw(plot_list$Gene2)
```

Comment: You really helped so much. Thanks a lot. This works for me.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can *group* your data by *gene*, make *plots* for two (or more) groups withing *grouping gene* using `facet_wrap()` (which also adjust y limits based on the range of `Readings` values withing the group), and save the plots with simple and clear pipeline:

```
dir.create(temp <- tempfile())                            

dat %>%
  group_by(Biomarkers) %>%
  group_walk(
    ~ ggsave(
      paste0(.y, '.png'), 
      ggplot(
        .x,
        aes(
          x      = TimePoint,
          y      = Readings,
          colour = Scale,
          group  = Scale
          )
        ) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point(size = 1.5) +
        facet_wrap( ~ Groups, nrow = 1) +
        ggthemes::theme_few() +
        scale_x_continuous(
          breaks = c(42.5, 47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5),
          labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
        ) +
        scale_color_viridis_c(breaks = c(5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90)) +
        theme(legend.key.height = unit(0.155, 'npc')) +
        ggtitle(.y), 
      device = 'png',
      path = temp
      )
  ) %>% 
  invisible()

# Saving 6.96 x 6.02 in image
# Saving 6.96 x 6.02 in image  

list.files(temp)

# [1] "Gene1.png" "Gene2.png"
```

Read the plots:

```
imgs <- lapply(
  list.files(temp),
  function(i){
    png::readPNG(file.path(temp, i))
  }
)
```

View plot for *Gene1*:

```
grid::grid.raster(imgs[[1]])
```

[image: Gene1]

View plot for *Gene2*:

```
grid::grid.raster(imgs[[2]])
```

[image: Gene2]